# how to breakpoint to webpack in intellij IDEA?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to breakpoint to webpack Source Code in Intellij IDEA 2016.2 for Mac.

it tips:

```
 To debug "build-distributor" script, make sure $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION string is specified as the first argument for node command you'd like to debug.

For example:

{ "start": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js" }
```

but,where is add this code when debugging webpack?

Comment: What command do you execute?

Answer (score 3):

Today I had the same problem and found the place where to put the NODE_DEBUG_OPTION. You have to change or create a new npm script which points to the javascript file. For example, I wanted to set breakpoints in an webpack plugin so my original npm script looked like

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
},
```

my new script with the NODE_DEBUG_OPTION looks like

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
},
```

I'm working on an Windows Machine. Thats the reason why my NODE_DEBUG_OPTION is between two "%" and yours have an "$" in front of.